# How can I open files from directory?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
import Image
sizes = [(120,120), (720,720), (1600,1600)]
files = ['a.jpg','b.jpg','c.jpg']

for image in files:
    for size in sizes:
      Image.open(image).thumbnail(size).save("thumbnail_%s" % image)
```

How can I open files from directory? So input will be directory, not `files`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

```
from glob import glob
files = glob('%s/*.jpg' % mydir)
for image in files:
    (...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of files in a directory with `os.listdir`. You can use `os.path.isfile` to filter files and `re.match` to find files matching a specific name/extension.

Something like this:

```
import re
import os

folder = 'images'
files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, f))]
jpegs = [f for f in files if re.match(r'.*\.jpe?g', f) != None]
```